# Running a Windows Phone 8.0 application in the background/after minimized

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-process

I have made a **Windows Phone 8.0** application with **Visual Studio 2012** that listens to a clap from the microphone and it pauses the current playing song. It is working very fine. But I want to open  the app and click the button to start listening and when I go to another app the functionality does not work.
What I need is to make my application run in the background like even in home screen when I sound a clap it should pause the song. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Not possible to listen to microphone with a background agent

check this link:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
Unsupported APIs:     
System.Windows.Media A/V Capture     
Microsoft.Xna.*
```

Comment: Thank you fro the answer. Isn't there even a complex method to achieve this ?

Comment: If you can't access microphone, I supposed there's no possible method...more you play with WP8 more you get used to things that are not possible or easy to do!

Comment: nice idea :) So any suggestions to achieve my goal ?

Comment: I guess you didn't read well what I said. Can't access microphone, so, no input allowed....which means it is not possible. there's no workaround! By the way, i guess you can accept this as the answer...because you will not be able to do what you want!

Comment: Okay. Yes I will for sure. But let me please wait little time because I personally do not believe the word "impossible" in computer stuff :)

Comment: okay. I also did not believe..but since I started working with WP8 it started to be a word used more times than I wanted, unfortunately

Comment: "Impossible" can also be "Restricted by platform API". Which is the case here. So it is impossible for standard third-party apps.